# I can't see what's wrong with my code. I can't write a simple calculator

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I writing this this code for a Stepik course. Description of the task says:

> Write a simple calculator that reads three lines from user input: the
>   first number, the second number, and the operation, and then applies
>   the operation to the entered numbers ("first number" "operation"
>   second number") and displays the result.
>
> Supported operations: +, -, /, *, mod, pow, div, where  mod is taking
>   the remainder of the division,  pow — exponentiation,  div — integer
>   division.
>
> If division is performed and the second number is 0, output the string
>   "Division by 0!".
>
> Please note that the input program comes real numbers.

I tried near 10 different times and the program shows me the same error.

One of my tries:

```
a,b,c = float(input()), float(input()), str(input())
if c == '+':
    print(a+b)
elif c == '-':
    print(a-b)
elif c == '*':
    print(a * b)
elif c == '**':
    print(a**b)
elif c == 'mod':
    if b == 0:
        print('Деление на 0!') # Division by 0!
    else:
        print(a%b)
elif c == '/':
    if b == 0:
        print('Деление на 0!') # Division by 0!
    else:
        print(a/b)
elif c == '//':
    if b == 0:
        print('Деление на 0!') # Division by 0!
    else:
        print(a//b)
```

In my IDLE (PyCharm) all works good, the program outputs "Division by 0!" where it needs. But when I check my code on browser it outputs:

```
Failed test #5. Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong.
```

Comment: And what is the input of test #5?

Comment: @interjay, I used 5.0, 0.0, mod and the same for /. with other operations all is normal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You implemented `**` and `//` but the spec calls for `pow` and `div`.